# How to dynamically change a PivotTable's source file location in VB.NET?

Tags: excel, vb.net, pivot-table, vsto, office-addins

I'm trying to dynamically change a pivot table's source file.  I've found `PivotTable.ChangeConnection`, but no example of setting just the source file location.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
strCSV_Locaiton="\\...\massprops.csv"

MPPivotTable.ChangeConnection(strCSV_Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a [WorkbookConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookconnection?view=excel-pia) object that represents the new connection for the `PivotTable`. Here's an example that prints all the connections to the debug window:

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```

Note, the `ChangeConnection(WorkbookConnection)` method can only be used with a `PivotTable` that is connected to an external data source. A run-time error will occur if the `ChangeConnection(WorkbookConnection)` method is used with a `PivotTable` that uses data stored on a worksheet as its data source.

Comment: conn.OLEDBConnection.CommandText returns the named cell that contained the old method of setting the table location

I've been able to set CommandText to the new location, but the pivot table will not refresh.  The error states that the table might not exist.

Comment: This might have more to do with the way the csv file is set up with "|" instead of a simpler comma.

Comment: This is from the Query Settings - Source:

= Csv.Document(File.Contents(GetValue("CSVLocation")),[Delimiter="|", Columns=24, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

CSVLocation is the named cell location of the previous entry point for the outside file.

Comment: here's the text from the advanced editor of the pivot table

let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(GetValue("CSVLocation")),[Delimiter="|", Columns=24...

I'm trying to change "CSVLocation" to a location input by the user

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. Currently I have a power PivotTable with an external connection to a csv file. I want to programmatically change that connection to different file on my network. 

Dim connection As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookConnection = wb.Connections(MPPivotTable.PivotCache().WorkbookConnection.Name)
Dim newConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\l46633\Downloads;Extended Properties='Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(|)'"
connection.OLEDBConnection.Connection = newConnectionString